# Correlation Function syntax

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, custom-function

---

**Hello,**

I'm attempting to develop a **function** that takes two expressions as inputs: the name of the platform (for instance, "PS2") and the kind of reviews (for instance, "critic score").

**The function's goal is to determine the Pearson connection between the platforms' overall sales and the type of ranking ('critic score'):**

```
def corfunc(Platform, score_type):
    df5 = df_new[(df_new.platform==Platform)&(df_new[score_type].notna())][['total_sales',score_type]]
    df5.plot(x=score_type, y='total_sales', kind='hexbin', gridsize=20, sharex=False, alpha=1)
    correlation=df5.corr(method='pearson')
    
    if [[correlation > 0.7]]:
        result=print(correlation)
        print('There is a strong positive connection')
    elif [[correlation < -0.7]]:
        print('There is a strong negative connection')
    else:
        result=print('No/weak connection')
    print(result)
```

**Here's an example of the data which is already filtered:**

```
pita=df_new[(df_new.platform=='PS3')&(df_new['critic_score'].notna())][['total_sales','critic_score']]
```

```
pita.head(3)

total_sales critic_score
16  21.05   97.0
34  13.79   83.0
37  13.33   88.0
```

**I would appreciate some assistance with the syntax relating to the outcomes of **if/else** statements:** When I check the function output, it appears that it doesn't take into account the correlation scores, showing as though there is a fully and positively connected relationship. I would like for my function to take into account multiple correlations, rather than just checking a correlation of a variable to itself. Thanks!

```
corfunc('PS3', 'critic_score')
```

```
              total_sales  critic_score
total_sales      1.000000      0.379961
critic_score     0.379961      1.000000
There is a strong positive connection
None
```

Comment: Do you wish to do multivariate correlation rather than pairwise correlation?

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your response.

I'll try to be more specific: I want that function to consider both correlations: the correlation between the variable and itself and the correlation with the second variable.

Answer (score 1):

To get the correlation of one variable with another, use [Series.corr](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.corr.html#pandas.Series.corr):

```
correlation = df["critic_score"].corr(df["total_sales"])
```

As already noted, the correlation of a variable with itself is always 1.

The reason for the problems in your current code is that [`df.corr()` returns a dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html#pandas.DataFrame.corr). `df.corr() > .7` does not return a single True/False value, but another dataframe, containing True if each value in the original dataframe > .7 and False if not.

For this reason the `df.corr() > 7` cannot be used as the condition in an `if` statement. You would need to select one of the values within the dataframe, or use `(correlation > .7).any(axis=None)` to check if any of the values are above .7. (Putting the dataframe in square brackets prevents an error being raised but does not do anything useful.) But it's easier to calculate the correlation between the two series instead, as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

The correlation to itself will always be 1.0 as it is follows the exact same data. As in you example

```
          total_sales  critic_score
total_sales      1.000000      0.379961
critic_score     0.379961      1.000000
```

The correlation between total_sales and critic_score is 0.379 while the 1's in correlation is not very interesting as they compare towards themselves.

One way to make it a bit more intuitive is to use heatmaps to visualize the correlations rather than just look at the pure numbers.

I often use seaborn heatmap which can take a DF like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
# With annotation true you get the values within the squares
sns.heatmap(dataframe, anoot=True)
```

---

To incorporate the correct pairwise funcitonality with sentences it would be something like this (like Stuart mentioned):

```
def corfunc(Platform, score_type):
    df5 = df_new[(df_new.platform==Platform)&(df_new[score_type].notna())][['total_sales',score_type]]
    df5.plot(x=score_type, y='total_sales', kind='hexbin', gridsize=20, sharex=False, alpha=1)
    correlation = df5["critic_score"].corr(df["total_sales"], method='pearson')


    if correlation > 0.7:
        result=print(correlation)
        print('There is a strong positive connection')
    elif correlation < -0.7:
        print('There is a strong negative connection')
    else:
        result=print('No/weak connection')
    print(result)
```

Comment: Please look at my first "if" statement and her result since I also use Seaborn heatmaps:

"There is a  strong positive connection".

This sentence has to be changed in order to include the association that is "less interesting".

the result should seem as follows:

"There is a weak connection between..."

In order to **first** count the week link between the two variables, how can I modify this function?

Comment: Added an edit with example implementation.

Comment: I've taken your and Stuart's advice into consideration, and it seems to be working. many thanks

Comment: @MaorOhayon If the answeres helped you, please do mark one of the answers as accepted answer before you move on, it greatly helps others that may see the thread in the future.

Comment: already done, thanks!
have a good one.